# Juego del pato, pato, pato, ganso

Tags: php, random

Tengo el siguiente código, para hacer un juego del [pato-ganso](http://www.vladimirklimsa.com/2011/02/juego-pato-pato-ganso.html) mediante `for` en PHP, pero simplemente no encuentro cómo hacerlo.

El juego consiste en que existen una `n` cantidad de jugadores, en este caso son 4, a partir de ello imprimir a los jugadores y definir qué va a ser cada uno de ellos. Por poner un ejemplo Maria 'es' ganso, juan es pato, y así sucesivamente a partir de una elección aleatoria.

```
for ($x=0; $x <4 ; $x++) { 

    for ($y=0; $y < $arr_name ; $y++) { //for para la cantidad de jugadores

        if () {//este va a decir quien es pato y quien es ganso

            break; //para dejar de elegir al ganso
        }
        if () { //este if va a decir si atrapo o no 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: que es lo que has intentado, como estas definiendo quien es el ganzo? y cuantas vueltas puede dar el for

Comment: lo he intentado de otra forma, pero con un solo for. Pensaba definirlo con un array.

Comment: Te puedo decir como plantearlo mas no hacertelo, mira puedes tomar un array como dices y lo llenas con nombres de los jugadores el ultimo campo del array lo usas para la persona que sera el que seleccione al ganzo. como hacer a quien ponerle ganzo pues con un random que vaya de 0 al ultimo indice del arreglo - 1, despues de esto con un random que sea de 0 o 1 lo pasas por un if para ver si lo atrapo y colocas a esa persona en el lugar del ganso y al ganso en el lugar del que selecciona

Comment: ¿En qué consiste el juego del pato-pato-pato-ganso? Ten en cuenta que muchos usuarios que podrían ayudarte pueden no conocer el juego. Añade una descripción más detallada del problema así como lo que lleves hecho y las dificultades que estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y consejos.

Comment: El juego consiste en que, haya un cierto numero de jugadores pueden ser 3, 4 o n numero. El caso es que deben de dar una vuelta y seleccionar a una persona para que esta sea el nuevo ganso, y asi sucesivamente mediante un ciclo, eligiendo a este de modo aleatorio. Sin embargo aun no he podido descifrar como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Es obligatorio utilizar el `for`?

Comment: si :( @KacosPro

Comment: @PedroM. ¿Y cuál es tu intención con el `for` externo? Además, mencionaste muy bien que hay "*una elección aleatoria¨" ¿buscaste información sobre esto en internet?